# Unir lineas continuas que cumplan cierta condición en una sola linea

Tags: notepad++

Tengo un csv con esta estructura que me gustaría convertir en lo siguiente a través de la función buscar y reemplazar de Notepad++:

TENGO:

> 6543210893, aqui tengo texto
>
> ""C:\Aquivaunaruta\

QUIERO:

> 6543210893, aqui tengo texto C:\Aquivaunaruta\

Es decir, me gustaría sustituir todas las dobles comillas que empiecen por "C:\Aquivaunaruta..." por un retorno a la linea anterior añadiendo un espacio.

No se si esto es posible.

Lo que necesito es esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias poner un pequeño fragmento de tu archivo y otro pequeño fragmento de como quedaria modificado? Es que casi no entiendo lo que quieres.

Comment: Hecho, a ver si de esta forma se entiende algo mejor..

Comment: Podrías utilizar otro editor como Atom https://atom.io/ o tienes alguna restricción para utilizar específicamente notepad++?

Comment: puedo usar cualquiera no habría problema

Answer (score 4):

Para hacer lo que deseas solo tienes que:

1. Ir a menú <kbd>**`Buscar`**</kbd> y seleccionar <kbd>**`Reemplazar`**</kbd> (o pulsar <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`H`</kbd>).
2. En  <kbd>**`Modo de búsqueda`**</kbd> seleccionar la casilla **<kbd>`extendido (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)`</kbd>**
3. Si el archivo tiene el fin de linea tipo Windows (`\r\n`, retorno de carro + salto de linea) deberás ingresar `\r\n""` como patrón en el cuadro de texto <kbd>**`Buscar`**</kbd>.
4. En el cuadro de texto <kbd>**`Reemplazar`**</kbd> poner un espacio.
5. Click en <kbd>**`Reemplazar todo`**</kbd>.

---

**Ejemplo en funcionamiento:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tu archivo solo contiene este patrón con esto tienes mas que suficiente. Para casos mas complejos se pueden usar expresiones regulares. Para ello se selecciona la casilla <kbd>**`Expresion regular`**</kbd> en <kbd>**`Modo de búsqueda`**</kbd>. Puedes ver la entrada correspondiente en la wiki de Notepad++:

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

en el notepadd++ tan solo apreta CTRL + F  , BUSCAR Y REEMPLAZAR en BUSCAR PON ""
y en REEMPLAZAR PON C:\Aquivaunaruta

Answer (score 0):

Si no entiendo mal, quieres eliminar el salto de línea y el string vacío`""`.

En el diálogo de buscar y reemplazar hay un recuadro que dice *modo de búsqueda*, asegúrate que esté marcada la opción *Extendida*. Con esto puedes buscar caracteres especiales como tabs, saltos de línea, etc.

Ahora prueba poner `\n""` en *buscar* y deja vacío el campo *reemplazar*

Estoy desde el celular así que estoy respondiendo de Memoria. Saludos