# Unir una línea que empieza de determinada forma con la línea anterior

Tags: regex, notepad++

Tengo el siguiente fichero:

```
""HKLM asdadas dasdadadsd
""PT
""HKLM asdadas dasdadadsd
""PT
""HKLM asdadas dasdadadsd
""PT
""HKLM asdadas dasdadadsd
```

Me gustaría que las lineas que empiezan por `""PT` se insertaran en la línea anterior, quitando las comillas.

```
""HKLM asdadas dasdadadsd PT
```

Para ello tendría que hacerlo con Notepad++. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿No es prácticamente lo mismo que ya habías preguntado en [*Unir lineas continuas que cumplan cierta condición en una sola linea*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/102370/127)? (que ni siquiera marcaste como respuesta aceptada!)

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente hay que eliminar el salto de línea y las comillas:

Buscar:

```
\R""PT
```

Reemplazar por:

```
 PT
```

- agregué un espacio al inicio (a gusto del consumidor).
- como verás, ni siquiera es del todo necesario usar una expresión regular el este caso.

Comment: Creo que para utilizar el modo extendido en notepad++, se debería cambiar la expresión a `\r\n""PT`. Tal cual la has puesto no me hace match.